# Calling a fragment from another fragment on click

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, onclicklistener

What I want to do is to call one fragment from another on click on item of listview. Program builds without errors however it crash on click on item. Btw I’m making here local Fragment_3 object, I have got already done it in my mainactivity, how to pass it to this function?

Fragment_1.java content:

```
public class Fragment_1 extends SherlockFragment implements OnItemClickListener{

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    return view;
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment Fragment3 = new Fragment_3();
    Integer fragmentId = (Integer) v.getTag();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentId, Fragment3);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

}
```

Comment: What's the crash detail? What holds v.getTag()?

Comment: Are your fragments all "live" at the same time? How are they being displayed? I'm guessing tabs?

Comment: is the value of the fragmentId == R.id.fragment_container ?!

Comment: @gunar i found somewhere taht v.getTag() holds id of actual fragment, im not sure that works

Comment: @bofredo probably not if it is crashing, but when i dont have any id on my fragments, all fragments are done on separate layouts

Comment: Why don't you set a global constant for fragmentId instead of doing that strange code? You're doing something that you don't know how it works

Comment: try to read out the value then. it feels like it doesnt work like it is atm

Comment: Are you trying to pass values to this other fragment or just call a method in it? I'm confused as to what you're end goal is.

Comment: I am not sure, but Integer fragmentId = (Integer) v.getTag(); is very suspectable. Might you should define an array storing all layout IDs and use position to loop and fetch the right one. Can you post the to show where you put your ID to tag?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that `v.getTag()` is null; So `Integer fragmentId = (Integer) v.getTag();` will end up in fragmentId being null. When unboxing that to an int you'll get a `NullPointerException`. Why don't you replace `fragmentId` in `fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentId, Fragment3);` with the id of the container that holds current instance of `Fragment_1`?

Comment: problem was that i didnt know where what variable keeps id of the current instance... but i got it: R.id.fragment_container, however what if i dont want to create `new Fragment_3()` ? if i want use that fragment from MainActivity. How to make it global or pass it id ?

Comment: What happens if you replace `fragmentdId` with` R.id.fragment_container`?

Comment: it is going well, `Fragment_3` replace current fragment, it looks like everything is okey

Comment: So is this the accepted solution for the question you posted?

Comment: yes, but i posted one more question up there: however what if i dont want to create new Fragment_3() ? if i want use that fragment from MainActivity. How to make it global or pass it id ?

Comment: You can't use that fragment instance. Create a new one instead.